# i need a quicksort where the first element of the relevant subarray is the pivot point

Tags: java

So I need to make a quicksort where you use the first element and compare it to all other elements and that first elements new position will become the pivot point. Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried anything or you're just looking for someone to do the homework for you?

Comment: Can you please share the code you have up until now and point out the position where you fail? That way we are better able to help you understanding the problem and solve it together.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating 3 lists and separate values depending on whether they are higher than pivot, lower than pivot, or equal to pivot. For example:

```
public static List<Integer> quickSort(List<Integer> n) {
        List<Integer> low = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> piv = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> high = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int pivot = n.get(0);
        for (Integer d : n) {
            if (d < pivot)
                low.add(d);
            else if (d > pivot)
                high.add(d);
            else
                piv.add(d);
        }
        low.addAll(piv);
        low.addAll(high);
        return low;
```